# Where do I see the list of recent notifications in google drive webapp?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I got a few notifications on my phone. Examples:

1. Someone commented on a doc and tagged me.
2. Another shared a file with me.

I'd like to see these notification on my desktop.

Where do I see the list of notifications in drive.google.com?

A direct link would be most appreciated.

Comment: See [Get Google Drive notifications](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6318501?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Comment: Hi Rubén, the link explains how to get to the notifications settings - not the list of notifications.

Comment: Google usually doesn't include mentions of features that doesn't exists :)

Comment: Anyway, first you have to turn notifications on, then use features of your web browser + your operative system to collect the notifications some way. Another option is to connect a tool / bot i.e. a Google chat bot, Slack, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Get Google Drive notifications](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6318501?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

---

- Turn on Notifications

On Windows browser notifications are managed in the action center
[image: Access Action Center]

Currently you can not access previous notifications as they are managed by the device not the app however the app does maintain a log of file edits so if you are after the date and time a comment was made or file shard with you you can go to the edit history of a specific document by clicking the last edit and reviewing previous versions

[image: Previous Versions]

Or by accessing the activity dashboard to review shared documents

[image: Activity Dashboard]